# For Loop..not looping throught all localStorage keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage

I'm trying to loop throught all my current localStorage items, but I cannot get to make it work properly, always last item is missing, not sure what else it could be.

```
function sortObject() {

    for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        if(localStorage.getItem(i) !== null) {

        let retrieveData = localStorage.getItem(i);
        let retrieveObject = JSON.parse(retrieveData);
        
        console.log(retrieveObject.index);
        }
    } 
}
```

[image: sadas]

```
Output: 
SortObject()
1
undefined
```

Comment: your keys are `1` and `2` but your loop is `0` and `1` should be `localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) );`

Comment: Thank you for your help @pilchard, sadly link you proposed as already answered. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: The duplicate has 13 answers with hundreds of up votes, surely one of them 'works'